# count the number of layers of battery anode

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, battery

I need to find out the number of anode layers of a cylindrical lithium battery based on the X-ray photo.

The right half of the image is the battery.

From left to right, there are separators, anode electrodes, and cathode electrodes.

First, I need to distinguish these three parts, and then use image processing to find out the number of layers of anode in the middle.

I tried using `OpenCV`'s `Sobel gradient` on the original image, and I could see some stripes roughly.

But the most challenging work is the top few stripes, which are not clear enough to be counted.

I hope someone could give me suggestions on how to process the image to find clear stripes, and then calculate their number.

Could we use some correlation information to make the last few stripes clearer? I am attaching my python source code for reference.

Thank you.

[image: original x-ray photo]

[image: Sobel gradient]

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
file_name = '213121_210105014503729_1504-1248_original_+down_NG.tif'
gray = cv2.imread(file_path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
sobelY = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
fig.suptitle(file_name)
plt.imshow(sobelY,cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Comment: Threshold the sobel result so that you have separate regions. Use morphology to clean up and close up. Then get contours and count the number of contours.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I believe this is the right way to go. Would you have any suggestions to distinguish the three parts on the image? It would make life easier if I could get rid of the unnecessary parts at the beginning. I tried to use sobel function in X direction but did not get nice boundaries among these three parts.

Comment: Are you talking about the bright region on the left side? You could count the number of non-zero pixels in each column. Find the column with the minimum and use that to crop the right side to keep only that data.

Comment: I do need to crop the left region, but more challenge is to distinguish the three parts at the right side. From left to right, there are separator, anode and cathode, and what I am really interested in is the anode part in the middle. There seems boundaries between the two adjacent ones, but I was wondering if there is a good method to get these boundaries so that I could crop them apart.